# Pass angular querystring to API controller as C# class by http.get

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am sending request. And i want map parameters to C# class in Asp.Net Core Web.API controller. When i write to my method property name as parameter, it is working. But, i write class then it gave me error like "The input was not valid."

I am sending my request by Postman as "Get"request. My request is
 http://localhost:5002/api/user/GetUsers?PageFirstIndex=0&IsSortAscending=true&PageSize=10&SortBy=Id

When i wrote like this, it is working and all parameters came with value.

```
public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUsers(string SortBy, bool IsSortAscending, int Page, byte PageSize)
{...}
```

But when i wrote like this as class, gave me error "The input was not valid.".

```
[HttpGet("GetUsers")]
public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUsers(QueryObject queryFilter)
{...}


public class QueryObject
{
   public string SortBy { get; set; }
   public bool IsSortAscending { get; set; }
   public int PageFirstIndex { get; set; }
   public byte PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should be use FromUri in api

Comment: GetUsers([FromUri] QueryObject queryFilter) ... This will work

Comment: Thanks but [FromUri] not worked. But [FromQuery] worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `FromQuery` attribute.

```cs
public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUsers([FromQuery]QueryObject queryFilter) {}
```

See the [model binding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Fred, Is there any way get rid of all [FromQuery] and [FromBody]? For example all get request [FromQuery] and all post requests [FromBody] by Default. Otherwise, i have to write all get method [FromQuery] @Fred

Comment: If you decorate the controller with the `[ApiController]` attribute (new in 2.1) it will attempt automatic interference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute

Comment: Thanks a lot. But on the contrary, I remove [ApiController] attribute from my controller and then it worked. @Fred